# Draw edges connecting vertices that are arranged in a circle

Tags: tikz-graphs

I would like to be able to draw lines (edges) between any two vertices within this circle of 10 vertices. I have been able to draw the vertices in the circle but I can't figure out how to draw the edges.

This is what I currently have:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{%
    mynode/.style={%
        circle, radius=2pt, draw=darkgray, fill=white
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, rotate=180] (epta) {};
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}{%
    \node[mynode] at (epta.corner \x) (e\x) {};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If there are any suggestions on a better way to draw a graph with nodes and edges, please let me know. I am new to drawing on LaTeX so I don't know the best way.

[image]

Comment: You have already named all edged, so draw from one to the other, like draw (e1) -- (e2);

Comment: Add `draw` option to `node` definition, like: `\node[draw, minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, rotate=180] (epta) {};`